# Microsoft Access 2007 subquery prompting for unnecessary parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, subquery, relational-database

I'm trying to create a query in Access 2007 that will return a list of all the apartments that are vacant in all of the apartment complexes that a company owns. The two tables that the query needs to run are Apartment and Rents.

[image]

I could not for the life of me figure out how to do such a query using the GUI in Access so I resorted to a custom SQL query:

```
SELECT Apartment.CIN, Apartment.AptNo
FROM Apartment
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT Rents.AptNo
    FROM Rents
    WHERE Rents.AptNo = Apartment.AptNo
);
```

When I run the query I am prompted to "Enter Parameter Value for Rents.AptNo". If I enter a valid number it does seem to affect the results in a favorable manner. Obviously this does not return all the vacant apartments, it simply returns all but those I have be forced to specify by AptNo.

Is there a way to convince Access that it doesn't need the Rents.AptNo value manually provided?

P.S. I am attempting to loosely follow this tutorial: http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html

Comment: Your Query uses AptNo, but the data model shows the column is called AptID

Comment: Try changing AptNo to aptID on last line

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo on an object name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's what I get for pulling an all nighter! Turns out I was attempting to use the AptNo column when I really meant to use the AptID column. Corrected code below for posterity.

```
SELECT Apartment.CIN, Apartment.AptID
FROM Apartment
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT Rents.AptID
    FROM Rents
    WHERE Rents.AptID = Apartment.AptID
);
```